# EntityFramework doesn't save letters as UTF-8 to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-5

I use EF 5.0 and MySql. EntityFramework save Turkish letters as English letters. For example I want to save name of an object as `'Çalışma'` but it saves as `'Calisma'` however I set format in database as UTF-8. Do you have any suggestion?